# как получить название картинки на почту php

Tags: php

Есть например `<img class="several__image" src="26.jpg"></img>` , и нужно с помощью кода php на почту прислать именно вот это значение из src - 26 (можно даже 26.jpg), Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

1. Регистрируйтесь в бесплатном SMTP сервере, чтобы рассылка шла именно от имени стороннего ресурса. Так как если ваши письма будут отмечать пользователи как спам, сайт с которого идет отправка сообщения ваш полетит на дно SEO. Даже если письма будут приходить только вам с названиями фото, то все равно может случиться тоже самое.
2. Пока мой ясновидящий выезжает из дома, чтобы прочесть ваши мысли, может вы упростите задачу и укажете при каких обстоятельствах нужно чтобы названия фото отправлялись? Пользователь загрузил фото? Нажал на кнопку?

Comment: Извините, думал понятно разьяснил что нужно делать, http://maslianik.website/phone/ - вот при каких обстоятельствах загружается картинка

Comment: Ну так и в чем сложность? Есть форма, Есть кнопка "Заказать" type="submit", есть фото разных Iphone каждому из них присваиваете value отдельное и будут чудеса.  Вообще чтобы вам помогали здесь решать задачу, вам как минимум нужно привести свой пример кода, что вы УЖЕ сами сделали.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду знать в следующий раз

Comment: https://htmlacademy.ru/tutorial/php/forms  там подробно объяснено как работают формы, если вы их еще не изучали.

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос был связан с тем как именно получить значение в src, то...

```
$src = '<img class="several__image" src="26.jpg"></img>';
preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/i', $src, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```